# Problem with Greenaddress 2of2 Recovery

Tags: green-address

I'm encountering an unforeseen problem with 2o2 Recovery procedure. 
I followed all the instruction at https://github.com/greenaddress/garecovery, I've correctly installed Ubuntu for Windows, I've correctly run through all the steps until:

```
$ garecovery-cli 2of2 --nlocktime-file /path/to/downloaded/nlocktimes.zip -o garecovery.csv
```

I've passed the correct `nlocktimes.zip`, I've entered the right mnemonic, but the output I see is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rene/.local/bin/garecovery-cli", line 7, in <module>
    sys.exit(recoverycli.main(sys.argv))
  File "/home/rene/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/garecovery/recoverycli.py", line 86, in main
    recovery = get_recovery(clargs.args, mnemonic, seed)
  File "/home/rene/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/garecovery/recoverycli.py", line 61, in get_recovery
    return TwoOfTwo(mnemonic, seed, options.nlocktime_file)
  File "/home/rene/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/garecovery/two_of_two.py", line 25, in __init__
    zipdata = gacommon._unzip(self.compressed_zip, chaincode)
  File "/home/rene/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gaservices/utils/gacommon.py", line 35, in _unzip
    all_data.extend(_unzip(_fernet_decrypt(key, encrypted), key))
  File "/home/rene/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gaservices/utils/gacommon.py", line 11, in _fernet_decrypt
    assert wally.hmac_sha256(key[:16], data[:-32]) == data[-32:]
AssertionError
```

Can anybody help me?
Many thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have entered a valid mnemonic, but it cannot decrypt the nlocktime.zip file. It could be that the mnemonic you entered is not the one associated with the wallet (which can be used to decrypt the nlocktime.zip).

I replicated your error by using another mnemonic in one of the examples (`garecovery/examples/example_2of2.sh`):

```
$ garecovery-cli --network=testnet --mnemonic-file garecovery/tests/test_data/mnemonic_2.txt 2of2 --nlocktime-file garecovery/tests/test_data/compressed_1.zip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/recovery/venv/bin/garecovery-cli", line 7, in <module>
    sys.exit(recoverycli.main(sys.argv))
  File "/tmp/recovery/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/garecovery/recoverycli.py", line 86, in main
    recovery = get_recovery(clargs.args, mnemonic, seed)
  File "/tmp/recovery/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/garecovery/recoverycli.py", line 61, in get_recovery
    return TwoOfTwo(mnemonic, seed, options.nlocktime_file)
  File "/tmp/recovery/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/garecovery/two_of_two.py", line 25, in __init__
    zipdata = gacommon._unzip(self.compressed_zip, chaincode)
  File "/tmp/recovery/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gaservices/utils/gacommon.py", line 35, in _unzip
    all_data.extend(_unzip(_fernet_decrypt(key, encrypted), key))
  File "/tmp/recovery/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gaservices/utils/gacommon.py", line 11, in _fernet_decrypt
    assert wally.hmac_sha256(key[:16], data[:-32]) == data[-32:]
AssertionError
```

For sure, the error message will have to be improved.

If you need further assistance and you feel you may reveal too much information about your situation, please send an email to info@greenaddress.it.